# Elasticsearch in an existing JHipster project - old entity does not get search api

Tags: elasticsearch, jhipster

I have added elastic search to project after creation.

I am able to see the search for user(default) and newly created entity.

Its not working for already existing entities.

Steps i follow to add elastic search -

1. In yo-rc.json file and add a line "searchEngine": "elasticsearch"
2. Yo jhipster
3. Entities regenrate

Answer (score 1):

Set `"elasticsearch": "elasticsearch"` in your existing entity JSON files.